# Tooltip on Drawer

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to change the "Open navigation menu" default tooltip for the Drawer option but I don't know where I need to go.

I'm making an app and I want to change the tooltip, it's invisible in the code so I don't know how to change it

Comment: can you show  the code of what you have done so far?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can change the tooltip by customizing it through `appBar`, as below:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('test'),
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
              },
              tooltip: 'Something else',
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
         // whatever you want to display when nav drawer opens
```

Now when you long press on nav drawer icon, you'll see 'Something else' as the tooltip.

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Good to know. Please accept and upvote my answer so that it'll be helpful for others as well :-)

Comment: Just FYI. This will break navigation, so back arrow is no longer displayed.